# When is returning stale state acceptable?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I am looking at possible combinations of a consistency with replication factor with Cassandra.

For this combination

```
RF 2
Write CL ONE
Read CL ONE
```

R. Strickland in Cassandra High Availability says

```
sometimes returning stale data is acceptable
```

How it comes that this is acceptable?
As I understand stale state does not reflect reality,original database could be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really depends on your application - you might tolerate reading the "stale" data, or losing some data because node where you did write at `ONE` is down...

For example, quite often, when writing time series from sensors, people may tolerate losing several data points, but achieve very high write throughput.

For reading, there could be also cases, where the answering faster could be more important than showing up-to-date data.  Example, for example, may include something like "Google Finance" where it's not so important that user see the latest data point, but for user is more important to get response fast, especially when user has many stocks in portfolio...